# Open App store through iPhone Application

Tags: ios, objective-c

Is there any way to Open `Apple AppStore` with my iPhone Application ?

Comment: Yes, certainly. How is this related to Xcode?

Comment: @H2CO3 means ? want to switch user from my iPhone to app store.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, You Can do this Using :

If you have your application `URL`then.

`[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:

                                            @"itms-apps://YourApplicationLink"]];`

else you can create the `URL` with this.
[Link Maker](http://itunes.apple.com/linkmaker)

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

please see this apple QA Link https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1633/_index.html

provided by

```
 Company Name

    http://itunes.com/apps/<companyname>

    for example, http://itunes.com/apps/smule

    Application Name

    http://itunes.com/apps/<applicationname>

    for example, http://itunes.com/apps/ocarina

    Application by Company

    http://itunes.com/apps/<companyname>/<applicationname>

    for example, http://itunes.com/apps/smule/ocarina
```

**Launching the App Store from an iPhone application**

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa2008/qa1629.html

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In iOS6 there is the new **SKStoreProductViewController** http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/StoreKit/Reference/SKITunesProductViewController_Ref/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011852

Answer (score 0):

Use the `itms-apps:` or `itms-appss:` URL scheme.